# Creating Xtext plugin for Eclipse - error during Plug-ins validation

Tags: eclipse, plugins, rcp, xtext, pde

I try to publish my DSL grammar into a plug-in, following that [tutorial](https://kthoms.wordpress.com/2010/11/12/setting-up-a-rcp-product-for-a-dsl/). Everything is fine until running plug-ins validation, in Run > Run Configurations. Following validation error occurs:

[image]

I have made research in the net, but answers aren't satisfactory. I installed PDE and RCP extension to eclipse.

I also tried to directly export plug-in, but there was following error:

```
 Software being installed: PlugTest 0.0.0   

(org.xtext.example.plugtest.product.product 0.0.0)
 Missing requirement: EMF XML/XMI Persistence 2.13.0.v20170609-0707 (org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi 2.13.0.v20170609-0707) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore [2.13.0,3.0.0)' but it could not be found
```

EDIT: I added some plugins like org.eclipse.core.net and org.eclipse.ui.ide.application. Validation passes fine, but funny thing happens later: attempts to run configuration causes following errors:

> Framework arguments:  -product org.xtext.example.plugtest.product.product
>   Command-line arguments:  -product org.xtext.example.plugtest.product.product -data /home/hubert/Eclipse_Projects/pluginTest/../runtime-PlugTest.product -dev file:/home/hubert/Eclipse_Projects/pluginTest/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/PlugTest.product/dev.properties -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -consoleLog
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2017-10-31 08:28:19.638
>   !MESSAGE Unable to load resource platform:/plugin/org.xtext.example.plugtest.product/Application.e4xmi

Comment: which xtext and mwe version do you use? which guava version do you have?

Comment: Xtext version is 2.11.0, Eclipse IDE is 4.7.1a. My Guava version is 21.0.0.v20170206-1425, but also version 15.0.0 is available.

Comment: The `Unable to load ... Application.e4xmi` problem is not related to the missing requirement. The answer to the original question was to add the missing plug-in(s) to the target platform. Adding the `org.xtext.example.plugtest.product` plug-in might fix the new problem. But you better ask this separately with more details about the run configuration you use.

Comment: I found I have to add each missing plug-in manually when I want to export. In case of "Run configuration" it's easier, because I can hit "Add Required plug-ins", which deals everything automatically.

Comment: You need xtext 212 and mwe 291 for that new guava